# Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64) is displayed. How do I get to GUI?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Installing Ubuntu on Win 11 Lenovo IdeaPad Slim 5. Installed prerequisites and downloaded Ubuntu, named and passworded it but now the terminal displays: `Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)`

My question is, what is the proper syntax to get to the GUI interface?

Comment: [*documentation*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps)

Comment: I am not sure. Did you do a complete install?  I have Ubuntu 22.04 current running here

Comment: Provide your configuration file for WSL which indicates your WSLg configuration

Answer (score 1):

> what is the proper syntax to get to the GUI interface?

The [*primary* design for WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) is to run as a command-line/terminal developer tools.

While you can run GUI *applications*, running an Ubuntu GUI *interface* is much more difficult (and overall, not recommended outside a proof-of-concept).

As mentioned in the doc linked in the comments, WSL2 now supports running GUI applications right out of the box.  Just install the graphical application, run it, and it will display on the *Windows* desktop.

If you are wanting to run Ubuntu Desktop (based on Gnome), then (again, not recommended, but) see these posts on Ask Ubuntu:

- [Opening Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop on WSL2](https://askubuntu.com/q/1252007/1165986)
- [Cannot start gnome-session after enabling Systemd on latest WSL2](https://askubuntu.com/q/1442663/1165986)

If running Ubuntu Desktop is your primary use-case, then I recommend using a virtual machine instead of WSL.